# How to run a second instance of MS Teams for Linux?

Tags: linux, microsoft-teams

I would like to run MS Teams twice in Ubuntu - and be logged into different accounts on each.

I tried to run `teams` from the command line with the `&` as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31092963/10276092 , And a few other tricks:

```
nohup dbus-run-session teams &
nohup dbus-run-session teams &
```

However the 'second' teams simply brings the first application to the foreground.

Is there a bash or other solution? Is this a situation for a container?

Comment: "Microsoft Teams will support using multiple work accounts on its desktop apps. The functionality is not expected until the second half of 2022. At the moment, you have to log out of one account and log in to a different account to switch."

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a second instance of teams in your browser?

Comment: Have you tried running it as a different logged on user using the same X11 session?  I don't understand why that wouldn't work.  I don't have teams installed on my linux box but I have used this method (with `xhost +`) to do similar things in the past.  It should provide you with two distinct profiles and the app shouldn't be allowed to know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you might get Teams running in two windows simultaneously, you probably get into trouble when signing out in one of them. Because the login token on signout would likely be deleted for both windows.

So yeah, I'd say your best bet is installing MS Teams in a confined environment. You may choose to use a container or try out Snap. Usually Snaps store their data in different places compared to bare metal.